# Difference between 'roam' and 'ramble'

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences, synonyms

Both of these words mean "move about aimlessly or without any destination".
**Is there any difference between them? Is there any context in which you'd use "ramble" instead of "roam", or vice versa?**


P.S. I know about the other meaning of "ramble", which is "continue talking or writing in a desultory manner". I'm specifically asking about the first meaning and how it's different from "roam".

Comment: Are you asking about the song lyric "I've roamed and rambled, and I followed my footsteps / To the sparkling sands of her diamond deserts"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The difference is largely one of scope. Roaming implies moving aimlessly over a very large area, while rambling is more localized or indefinite regarding the area traversed.** The two words are indeed listed as synonyms in Oxford Dictionaries, but are often defined as

> **Roam**
>
> 1. To move about or travel aimlessly or unsystematically, especially over a wide area:
>
> "Tigers once roamed over most of Asia."
>
> (Source: Oxford Dictionaries)

And

> **Ramble**
>
> 1. To walk for pleasure, typically without a definite route.
>
> "We rambled around the neighborhood for a while after dinner."
>
> (Source: Oxford Dictionaries)

Comment: With rambling, also, you would tend to have a specific destination in mind (often back where you started), even if you're not sure which route you'll take.  I think the key difference is that "roam" is a simple description of movement, whereas ramble is actually an **activity**, ie an end in itself.  To say that a tiger rambles, for example, suggests that it's doing so just for the sake of it, ie for fun, rather than trying to find something to eat for example.

Comment: @Max Williams Very good points! I hadn't thought of those nuances, but they are very much a part of the difference between the two verbs in question.